# Most efficient way of avoiding loops to create data.frame

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data.frame which includes the runs scored in each innings of baseball games as a character vector.

I want to create a new data.frame which lists the number of runs in each innings for each game. I can do this with a loop but appreciate that this is too slow for any reasonable number of observations and that the `rbind` method shown is also not ideal.

The number of innings may vary and an x indicates that the team did not need to bat in 9th inning as game was already won.

```
library(stringr)

data <- data.frame(gameID=c("a","b","c"),innings=c("002100000","30000000x","10101010101"))

for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  box <- as.integer(str_split(data$innings[i], "")[[1]])

  tempdf <- data.frame(box,id=data$gameID[i])

  if(i!=1) {
    df <- rbind(df,tempdf)
  } else {
    df <- tempdf 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using lists with `lapply`:

```
library(dplyr)  # for bind_rows -- you can also use do.call(rbind, list)
innings <- str_split(data$innings, "")
names(innings) <- data$gameID
innings <- lapply(innings, function(x) data.frame(box = x))
bind_rows(innings, .id = "id")
```

Comment: twice faster as my solution :o)

Comment: and 8+ times faster than the original when applied to some real data

Answer (score 1):

This helps a bit (30%):

```
res <- vector("list", nrow(data))
for(i in seq_along(res))
  res[[i]] <- data.frame(box=as.integer(str_split(data$innings[i], "")[[1]]),
                         id=data$gameID[i])
do.call(rbind, res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is faster,

```
library(splitstackshape)
data$innings <- gsub('', ' ', data$innings)
cSplit(data, 'innings', ' ', 'long')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty fast:

```
## Defined these separately just for readability
innings <- as.character(data$innings)  # or use 'stringsAsFactors=FALSE' when defining the data frame
box <- unlist(strsplit(innings, ""))
id <- rep(data$gameID, nchar(innings))

## To get a character matrix back
cbind(box, id)

## To get a data frame back
data.frame(box=box, id=id, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Using a matrix is faster, but if you want to have mixed classes use a data frame. Also, for a data frame, it's faster to use characters than factors (thus the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` argument). If you want `box` to be numeric, you can wrap it in `as.integer` (but then the matrix option wont work, of course).